# How to view all class members of a user-created object

Tags: python, vim, vim-plugin

With SuperTab and Omnicomplete, one can do something like:

```
import random
random.
```

and, after pressing Tab, all of the associated class members will pop up along with their documentation. Getting these members can also be achieved by doing:

```
import random
print dir(random)
```

Where Omnicomplete seems to fall short (unless I've missed something) is exemplified in the following example:

```
import mechanize
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.
```

After pressing Tab in this case, none of the associated class members of the user-created object are visible using Omnicomplete, and a `pattern not found` message is displayed. However, when one does:

```
import mechanize
br = mechanize.Browser()
print dir(br)
```

it's clear that there are members which could be displayed.

Is there a way to get the class members in the second case to become visible?

Comment: Is this a Python coding question?

Comment: You can not know the members until you know which kind of object you got back from the function. To know this you have to run it.

Comment: @Matthias So in a more traditional IDE where this feature is available, the code is being run in order to make that information visible?

Comment: I am using PyCharm and it usually highlights all the default object types, but it can also infer simple function\object declarations to show the auto-completion. In a more complicated situation one might add a docstring, showing which type is used for certain variable and that will show up in auto-completion as well. To answer your previous question - IDE doesn't run your code, it merely parses it, if it can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jedi-vim](https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi-vim) seems to be popular python completion these days.

Note: I do not have any personal experience with this plugin.